# How to map two layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-design-library

I have 2 layouts in xml.

XML:

```
<TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/table"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="470dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="35dp">
</TableLayout>
<FrameLayout
         android:id="@+id/imageLayout"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="470dp"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
         android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="45dp">
</FrameLayout>
```

Table Layout is for creating 10X4 cellslike--https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYPLT.png
and FrameLayout is for showing the image on 10X4 cells. now am doing drap and drop images, how to find image in which cell on TableLaout?

Answer (score 0):

If you have to show only 4 part of image as in the provided link then you can use table layout like this:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TableRow
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imv1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_manual_icon"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imv2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_manual_icon"
        />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imv3"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_manual_icon"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imv4"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_manual_icon"
        />

</TableRow>
```

Like above you can find the image view reference in your activity or fragment and you can set image resources for it on their.

If you have table for more number of rows then It should better if you use GridView.
For more about GridView please refer [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html).

Comment: I need 10X4 grids and drag and drop on that grid, and image size can change if change means need to show in two or more cells

Answer (score 0):

If you can use GridView instead of TableLayout
check this https://blahti.wordpress.com/2011/10/03/drag-drop-for-android-gridview/ answer

Comment: I need 10X4 grids and drag and drop on that grid, and image size can change if change means need to show in two or more cells

Comment: have you checked given link

Comment: use given link for reference not exactly as answer